# how to show each data from table

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I want to show the table in my PHP page, my code is:

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM users_registration"; 
$result = pg_query($conn,$query);

$i=0;
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{
    $vm_array[$row[0]]=$row[0];
    $i++;
}
```

`username` values in table are:

```
 David
 amitra
 a
 David
 emilio
 Atul
 john
 rohit
 john
```

But my page shows only:

```
 David
 amitra
 a
 emilio
 Atul
 john
 rohit
```

How to show all the missing data e.g. `david`, `john`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `$vm_array[$row[0]]=$row[0];` overwrites each occurrence of the value of `$row[0]`, for example, 'David' and 'john', because you're using the actual value as a hash key. So, you cannot have a value more than once in your "array". Try `$vm_array[] = $row[0];` or `$vm_array[$i] = $row[0];` instead. But then you don't have a hash, I know. It's just to show the difference.

Comment: :) i am using $vm_array[$i] = $row[0]; in the past it works, but when i GET this page problem occurs, thats why i m using this

Answer (score 4):

the entry of the array is override with the same username

so change

```
$vm_array[$row[0]]=$row[0];
```

to

```
$vm_array[]=$row[0];
```

or to

```
$vm_array[$i]=$row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a override issue in php. here $vm_array[$row[0]] overridies the all duplicate value

u must use

$vm_array[$i]=$row[0];

then u can print the values